Can't connect to my EC2 instance with SSM : SSM Agent is not online
I would like to use Session Manager to connect to my instance.
I have created a role with those policies :
AmazonEC2RoleforSSM
AmazonSSMFullAccess

And attached with my instance, from debian official AMI (I red al important "official" AMI embed SSM agent)

But i still have the message :

(I also tried with the Amazon Linux AMI but it is the same).
I saw somewhere that I have to create an AWS service endpoint for SSM. I created one (and restarted the instance) but it is the same.

Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?
Thanks

How's your Security group set up? Did you complete the setup on the Systems Manager side?

Firstly, dont assume the agent is installed & running :) - login to ec2 via SSH and confirm. Assuming the agent is running, there should be a log file from the agent which will give you an idea whats wrong.
If you want to use SSM with VPC endpoints(such as a private VPC), you actually need 3 endpoints, ssm, ec2messages and ssmmessages. Those endpoints have a security group which needs to allow the instance (or the VPC range) for them to be used.

You were right! the SSM agent was not installed. I thought it was installed on all "major" ami. Thanks
